# Counting the number of group in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have found an interesting problem.

A n*m matrix is given, with a such form:

```
11111111
11111001
11111001
10111111
10111111
11100111
11111111
```

The goal of the problem is to find the number of '0' blocks. On the previous example, there were 3 '0' blocks.

I don't understand how to solve this problem. I don't ask for any code, I would like to get some hints about how to solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly is a block?

Comment: @user2040251 Thank you for your edition. You are right I am not clear enough. A block is a group of '0' who are adjacent (bottom, up, left, right).

Comment: Not the best solution but one way to do it is to iterate over the matrix and do the flood fill algorithm every time you encounter a not-seen-before `0` cell. Once done, add the found cells to a data structure to indicate that they belong to the same block. Keep doing this until you've gone over the matrix and found all zero blocks.

Comment: To start with, Take a index at a time, if it contains a `0`. Check if the top, left, right, or bottom indices have `0` in them.

Comment: I VTC as too broad because there are probably many different equally good approaches.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: I think that *is* the best solution!  (Assuming the OP intends "block" to mean "connected component of 0s" -- the definition of "block" is still not 100% clear.)

Comment: @SimeonVisser Thank you, I didn't know about the flood fill algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use depth-first search to find connected components in a graph where vertices are cells with 0 and an edge between two vertices is present if two cell are adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Given your definition of block:
For every row you check if there are two (or more) contiguous zeros if that is the case you increase the 0's block count by 1 for each one of these occurrences.

You repeat the same  procedure for the columns of the matrix.

I am not sure from your description of the problem how you should count bigger blocks like:

```
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

Is this a single block?

Comment: Yes it is a single block